# Do frequency adverbs that go at the beginning of sentence need a comma? (Occasionally, Sometimes, etc.)

Tags: punctuation, commas, adverbs

Do frequency adverbs that go at the beginning of sentence need a comma?

Which of these alternatives, if any, is better?

- Occasionally, I play football with my friends.
- Occasionally I play football with my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As neither variant is confusing, I'd use either, depending on whether I thought a pause sounded natural / desirable.

> I often go swimming, and I love fishing, clay-pigeon shooting, and
>   bird-spotting. I often go dancing. Occasionally, I play football with
>   my friends.

but

> I do get a reasonable amount of exercise. Occasionally I play football
>   with my friends, but my real love is swimming.

If you want an authority to sanction this,

Chicago Manual of Style 5.69:

> "When [transitional adverbs] are used in such a way that there is no
>   real break in continuity and no call for any pause in reading, commas
>   should be omitted.

Transitional adverbs are traditionally even more attached to their following commas than adverbs of frequency.

Note that some frequency adverbs require inversion if fronted:

> Seldom / Rarely / Never does the king now venture beyond his palace walls.

Answer (score 1):

Comma "rules" are tricky. Most are best thought of as guidelines than rules.

Setting of introductory elements is indeed something that most sets of such rules would say you need a comma, so "by the rules" the form with the comma is the correct one.

Conversely, if the *occasionally* was only the start of an introductory phrase then the same rule would have you not put a comma there, but after the rest of that phrase:

> Occasionally I play football with my friends, but I'm not a physically active person.

But again, any such rule is best thought of as a guideline. If you want to emphasise by setting a word off with a comma or de-emphasise by omitting one, and the result is understandable and unambiguous, then go for it.